# Storing a hexadecimal number in an int

Tags: c, loader, systems-programming

Trying to implementation of an absolute loader with input from : http://pastebin.com/k7VkA3xQ

Output currently obtained : http://pastebin.com/FiYPMWrZ

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


int dec(char hex[]){ //function converts a hex array of characters to its equivalent decimal value

int length,i,sum=0;
for(length=0;hex[length]!='\0';length++);

for (i = 0;hex[i]!='\0'; ++i,--length)
{
    if (hex[i]>='0' && hex[i]<='9') 
        sum+=(hex[i]-'0')*pow(16,length-1);
    else if (hex[i]>='A' && hex[i]<='Z')    
        sum+=hex[i]-'A'+10;
    else if (hex[i]>='a' && hex[i]<='z')    
        sum+=hex[i]-'a'+10;
}
return sum;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
char record[2],progname[10],startaddr[10],proglen[10],addr[10],len[10];
int start,address,diff,flag=1,decimal;
FILE *fptr;

if (access("Input.dat",F_OK)!=-1)
{
    fptr = fopen("Input.dat","r");
    printf("File opened successfully\n");
}
else
{
    printf("File opened unsuccessfully\n");
    exit(1);
}


fscanf(fptr,"%s",record);
if (strcmp(record,"H")==0){
    fscanf(fptr,"%s",progname);fscanf(fptr,"%s",startaddr);fscanf(fptr,"%s",proglen);
}

fscanf(fptr,"%s",record);
while(strcmp(record,"T") == 0 ){
    fscanf(fptr,"%s",addr);fscanf(fptr,"%s",len);
    if (flag)
        sscanf(startaddr,"%x",&start);
    else
        start = address; //'start' fails to store the hex value of 'address'

    sscanf(addr,"%x",&address);
    diff = address - start;
        while((diff--)>0){
            printf("%x              xx\n",start++);
    }
    decimal = dec(len)%3==0?dec(len)/3:dec(len)/3+dec(len)%3;
    while(decimal--){
        fscanf(fptr,"%s",addr);
        printf("%x              ",address++);   printf("%c%c\n",addr[0],addr[1]);   
        printf("%x              ",address++);   printf("%c%c\n",addr[2],addr[3]);   
        printf("%x              ",address++);   printf("%c%c\n",addr[4],addr[5]);   
    }
        fscanf(fptr,"%s",record);
}


return 0;
}
```

Not sure of how to make 'start' store the value of 'address'...at present..'start' prints from 1000H ... kindly help me in storing the hexadecimal value 'address' in the int 'start'...input and output files for the above implementation have been attached above...thx!

Comment: A "hexadecimal number" isn't a number, it's a character string.  On all standard computers a "number" is binary only.  One may *represent* a number as a decimal string or a hexadecimal string (or as "two thousand five hundred and fortytwo", if you wish), but to the computer the *number* is still just binary bits, spelled out, coded as "2542", or as "0x9EE", it's all the same numeric value.

Comment: You might consider `scanf` with the `%x` conversion, or `strtol` to handle the conversion.

Comment: (Your algorithm above is simply summing the digits, BTW.  To convert the hex representation to numeric you need to multiply `sum` by 16 ahead of each iteration.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the hexadecimal number is stored in a string `hex` with the form `0x...` or `0X...` or `...` where points are representing digits in **`16` base** then you can use the `sscanf()` function to store the value in an **integer number** (`decimalNumber` for the example below) in **`10` base**

```
sscanf(hex,"%x",&decimalNumber);
```

So for a complete example

```
char hex[100]="0xf";
int decimalNumber;
sscanf(hex,"%x",&decimalNumber);
printf("The value of decimalNumber is %d\n",decimalNumber);
```

the output will be

```
The value of decimalNumber is 15
```